# Django formset - Creating a formset of just ONE form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to implement a formset of just one form that will be edited with an user input. Currently I can only add all the forms I've currently declared but I only need one of those.

Im doing this:

```
    def oneForm(request):
Formset = formset_factory(testingForms)
form1 = Formset()
print(form1)
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class testingForms(forms.Form):
first = forms.DecimalField()
second = forms.CharField(max_length = 4)
third = forms.CharField(max_length = 1)
```

I want it to just be filled with the third form. So that when I use it in a template with the as_table() function, it prints out only the third form. I'm trying to avoid creating another class just for that... I don't feel like its done right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need 1 form, why use a formset instead of a single form?

In case you really do, just set max_num and min_num and extra to 1 and validate them.

```
Formset = formset_factory(testingForm, max_num=1, min_num=1, extra=1, validate_min=True, validate_max=True)
```

**EDIT**: Here's one solution.

forms.py

```
class FormA(forms.Form):
    first = forms.DecimalField()
    second = forms.CharField(max_length = 4)

class FormB(forms.Form):
    third = forms.CharField(max_length = 1)
```

views.py

```
from my_app.forms import FormA, FormB
from django.forms import formset_factory
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext

def your_view(request):
     form = FormA()
     # figure out how many instances of the third field you want
     number_of_forms = 3 # however you like
     FormsetFactory = formset_factory(FormB, min_num=number_of_forms, max_num=number_of_forms,extra=0,validate_min=True,validate_max=True)
     formset = FormsetFactory()
     if request.POST:
         # do something with post

     return render_to_response('your_template.html',{'form':form,'formset':formset}, RequestContext(request))
```

You just need to assign the `formset_factory` generator dynamically after figuring out the number needed.

There's more to rendering formsets properly, so take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: I need it because my objective is to generate X number of that form. Like user enters 5, I generate 5 third forms and NO first nor second forms. I implemented this but when printing it, it prints out all forms.

Comment: Just assign whatever number you need to a variable and use that for `max_num`, `min_num`, and `extra`. Otherwise I'm unclear on the question but might be able to help more w/ your full view and forms code.

Comment: Okay let me see how I can explain better my doubt, I want to print out the form named "third" X times. I know how to print it X number of times but I can't seem to print just that form and completely ignore the first and second one.

Comment: A formset is a way to display multiple instances of one form, which consists of defined fields. You are looking for a way to show one field a number of times, not a form. In order to do that, there's a few things you could do, but without knowing why you'd like to do this it's hard to suggest a specific method (could override the __init__ method of your form to generate a number of these fields, each needing a unique id; could have FormA consisting for fields 1 & 2 and use inlineformset_factory to have any number of FormB, consisting solely of field 3)

Comment: I see. Well I want to do is simulate an example of an encryption method. So I'm doing the Caesar Cipher, I take the word the user wants to encrypt as input. From that word, I get the length of it and create the number of forms depending on that input. If the word has 5 letters then 5 one letter input forms are created so the user types in one letter inside each input form and submits them individually to validate they are doing it right.

Comment: Added to the answer; in short, what you want is totally doable and best handled by Django's formsets

Comment: If any of this helped you, please upvote or accept answer :)

Comment: It did! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: No problem; formsets are tricky and take some practice to get the hang of, but the methods provided by Django allow a ton of flexibility as a result.